# How to extend brass pipe/conduit that is buried?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, pool

I need to relocate the above-ground junction box that is used by my pool light, and the conduit that feeds into the junction box is 1/2 inch brass pipe. I need to move it several feet further out, and need to know what my options are while maintaining code.

I think one option is to buy several more feet of brass pipe with some kind of coupling, only issue is the closest place that sells brass pipe is 40+ min away.

I believe the brass is threaded at the end going into the junction box. Can I use a threaded coupling that will connect to metal conduit?

Pics are below

[image: brass pipe]
[image: thread]

Comment: Are you certain it's brass, not copper conduit? Maybe include a picture or two showing the current conduit situation _and_ a picture inside the junction box. Also, "several feet" isn't likely to cause an issue, but include at least a rough distance back to the panel, as the total distance could impact the wiring in use.

Comment: @FreeMan, pics are attached.  I had two other electricians confirm they are brass. Regarding wiring, we can easily extend the steel conduit side as we haven't fed wire yet. For the brass side, this leads back to the pool. I can't check at the moment because the screw to the light is stripped, but if the pool installer did it right, there should be four feet of lead wire behind the light, which will allow me 1-2 ft of leeway on the junction box side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the brass pipe to another brass pipe with a coupling, brass around a pool is the best option as it will not rust. If you would not have said an electrician verified it was brass I would have suggested it was rigid conduit as it looks galvanized to me in the photo. Maintaining the brass will prevent any galvanic corrosion issues , 680.11 allows for rigid pvc but you mentioned pool light. If a wet-niche type light this would explain the comment if they did it right the extra wire. And the use of brass 680.23.8.b.   I would continue the brass for the additional safety it provides for grounding.

Comment: Rigid would have been my first guess too. I see that a lot down here in Fl. +